# Make conditional statements of attributes with templates in XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, grouping, xslt-1.0, conditional-statements

How can I get the value of an attribute and use it in a conditional statement. For example I have `<O Option="a" LineNr="1">` and this is element is a child under another parent element that gets grouped with other elements. So the condition I want is: if [value-of Option is null] then [do nothing] else-if [check if the value of the attribute of the element under the next parent element with the same value is empty]. And if there are for example 3 parent elements that contain this element with the Option attribute and if all of the attributes are NOT empty - then group them. 
I have the grouping done, but it is not connected with this attribute that I want to use now. So I need just the formulation of the conditional statements.

**edit: giving input and output desired examples**
Input example 1:

```
<Area>
     <Type>A</Type>
     <Street>
       <Position>5</Position>
       <House>
       <L Option="" LineNr="1">
       --> some elements
       </L>
       </House>
     </Street>
     <Street>
       <Position>5</Position>
       <Block>
       <O Option="" LineNr="1">
       --> some elements
       </O>
       </Block>
     </Street>
     <Street>
       <Position>6</Position>
       <House>
       <L Option="o" LineNr="1">
       --> some elements
       </L>
       </House>
     </Street>
     <Street>
       <Position>6</Position>
       <Block>
       <O Option="" LineNr="1">
       --> some elements
       </O>
       </Block>
     </Street>
   </Area>
```

And desired output:

```
<Area>
   <Type>A</Type>
     <Street>
       <Position>5</Position>
       <House>
       <L Option="" LineNr="1">
       --> some elements
       </L>
       </House>
       <Block>
       <O Option="" LineNr="1">
       --> some elements
       </O>
       </Block>
     </Street>
     <Street>
       <Position>6</Position>
       <House>
       <L Option="o" LineNr="1">
       --> some elements
       </L>
       </House>
       <Block>
       <O Option="" LineNr="1">
       --> some elements
       </O>
       </Block>
     </Street>
   </Area>
```

But if in the same position number, all the occurrences have a value in the Option attribute of L or O, then I want them arranged under the other occurrence of a position number. Like that:

Input example 2:

```
       <Area>
         <Type>A</Type>
         <Street>
           <Position>5</Position>
           <House>
           <L Option="" LineNr="1">
           --> some elements
           </L>
           </House>
         </Street>
         <Street>
           <Position>5</Position>
           <Block>
           <O Option="" LineNr="1">
           --> some elements
           </O>
           </Block>
         </Street>
         <Street>
           <Position>6</Position>
           <House>
           <L Option="o" LineNr="1">
           --> some elements
           </L>
           </House>
         </Street>
         <Street>
           <Position>6</Position>
           <Block>
           <O Option="a" LineNr="1">
           --> some elements
           </O>
           </Block>
         </Street>
       </Area>
```

Then the output will be:

```
     <Area>
       <Type>A</Type>
         <Street>
           <Position>5</Position>
           <House>
           <L Option="" LineNr="1">
           --> some elements
           </L>
           </House>
           <Block>
           <O Option="" LineNr="1">
           --> some elements
           </O>
           </Block>

           <House>
           <L Option="o" LineNr="1">
           --> some elements
           </L>
           </House>
           <Block>
           <O Option="a" LineNr="1">
           --> some elements
           </O>
           </Block>
         </Street>
       </Area>
```

as now position 6 is gone and its child elements are grouped under the upper occurrence position (which is 5 in this case in the same Type) as all of the attributes Option in the L or O elements had value (which can be either "a" or "o", if that is relevant).

And this is the XSLT which I am using now. It only groups the elements of the different occurrences of the same position numbers under one number:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

  <xsl:key name="streetByPosition" match="Street" use="concat(../Type, '|', Position)" />

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy><xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" /></xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- for the first Street in each Position -->
  <xsl:template match="Street[generate-id() =
                            generate-id(key('streetByPosition', concat(../Type, '|', Position))[1])]">
    <Street>
      <!-- copy in the Position element once only -->
      <xsl:apply-templates select="Position" />
      <!-- copy in all sub-elements except Position from all matching Streets-->
      <xsl:apply-templates select="
            key('streetByPosition', concat(../Type, '|', Position))/*[not(self::Position)]" />
    </Street>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- ignore all other Street elements -->
  <xsl:template match="Street" />
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Could you provide an example of your input XML and the output that you want?

Comment: @Ben - I have it in the following topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18228400/arrange-nodes-under-elements-according-to-some-conditions . But I decided to make this one just cuz it seem more clear what I am lost into. So you can review my overall problem in the other topic.

Comment: @Ben - I added some examples of input and desired output so you can understand the different cases I have and thought the conditional statements that I will need in order to cover all the cases.

Answer (score 0):

To obtain the desired result with ordering, you can group the nodes, for example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="/">
<Area>
    <Type>A</Type>  
  <xsl:for-each select="/Area/Street">  

    <xsl:sort select="Position"> </xsl:sort>  

      <xsl:sort select="node()[name(.)!='Position']"> </xsl:sort>

     <xsl:sort select="node()[name(.)!='Position']/node()/@Option"> </xsl:sort>      

    <xsl:copy-of select="." />
  </xsl:for-each>  
  </Area>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```